# php compiles timezone Europe/Berlin like UTC

Tags: php, datetime, plesk

I've been struggling with a weird problem today. For some reason my server pretends that the timezone 'Europe/Berlin' is UTC (it should be UTC+1). If I set the timezone to 'Europe/Brussels' for example, it converts the time correctly.

I've created some dummy code to test my server and on an online compiler. While the compiler works (I've used http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/), my server persists to have this issue.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$time = 'now';

$timezone1 = 'Europe/London';
$timezone2 = 'Europe/Berlin';
$timezone3 = date_default_timezone_get();
$timezone4 = 'Europe/Brussels';

$dateTime1 = new \DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($timezone1));
$timeParsed1 = $dateTime1->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');

$dateTime2 = new \DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($timezone2));
$timeParsed2 = $dateTime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');

$dateTime3 = new \DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($timezone3));
$timeParsed3 = $dateTime3->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');

$dateTime4 = new \DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($timezone4));
$timeParsed4 = $dateTime4->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');

echo($timezone1 . ': ' . $timeParsed1 . '<br>' . $timezone2 . ': ' . $timeParsed2 . '<br>' . $timezone3 . ': ' . $timeParsed3 . '<br>' . $timezone4 . ': ' . $timeParsed4);
?>
```

And here's the output that this genereates:

```
Europe/London: 2017-01-26 01:24:18+00:00
Europe/Berlin: 2017-01-26 01:24:18+00:00
UTC: 2017-01-26 01:24:18+00:00
Europe/Brussels: 2017-01-26 02:24:18+01:00
```

I've been trying to find the cause for this and searched here on Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find the reason. Here's a link to my phpinfo(): http://arma.jianji.de/phpinfo.php

And this is the dummy code on my server in action: http://arma.jianji.de/phptest.php

The server has been recently set up by me using Ubtuntu 16 LTS and Plesk Onyx. The server default timezone is set to London.

Unfortunately, I've been unable to find the reason for this. Do you have an idea?

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Update**

Because this has been brought up quite a lot, I've created a test where I set a default timezone by using:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');
```

Additionally, I've added "Europe/London" as default timezone in my php.ini.

The issue still persists: http://arma.jianji.de/phptest_default.php

Comment: What version of PHP is the server running?

Comment: I've attached the phpinfo so you can check all details, but it's "PHP Version 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1"

Comment: As far as i understand you are not able to set the different time zone. If this is a case then please try the date_default_timezone_set function you can get it's details at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: @Abbas I don't think you read the question.

Comment: Hi @Abbas,

Not exactly. I can set any timezone other than Europe/Berlin. So for example Europe/Brussels, which is UTC+1 like Europe/Berlin works. In order to make sure, I've added Europe/London as default timezone but the issue persists.

Here's the output:

    Europe/London: 2017-01-26 01:50:30+00:00
    Europe/Berlin: 2017-01-26 01:50:30+00:00
    Europe/London: 2017-01-26 01:50:30+00:00
    Europe/Brussels: 2017-01-26 02:50:30+01:00

Comment: If I'm understanding the issue correctly, this seems to be a bug in PHP 7s time zone definitions. Brussels and Berlin are both in UTC+01:00 ...
https://bugs.php.net/

Comment: Is your `tzdata` package up to date? You can simulate a package update with `apt-get -s install tzdata`

Comment: @Scopey Yes, I get: tzdata is already the newest version (2016j-0ubuntu0.16.04).

Comment: @jastend, what is the output of `date +%z` command?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov It's 0 for London and Berlin and 3600 for Brussels.

Comment: @jastend, there should be something wrong with tzdata. Check out the output of `zdump -V Europe/Berlin | grep 2017`. I'd recommend updating the timezone-data package and reinstalling PHP

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov I think you are right. The output shows this:

$ zdump -V Europe/Berlin | grep 2017
Europe/Berlin  Sun Mar 26 00:59:59 2017 UT = Sun Mar 26 00:59:59 2017 GMT isdst=0 gmtoff=0
Europe/Berlin  Sun Mar 26 01:00:00 2017 UT = Sun Mar 26 02:00:00 2017 BST isdst=1 gmtoff=3600
Europe/Berlin  Sun Oct 29 00:59:59 2017 UT = Sun Oct 29 01:59:59 2017 BST isdst=1 gmtoff=3600
Europe/Berlin  Sun Oct 29 01:00:00 2017 UT = Sun Oct 29 01:00:00 2017 GMT isdst=0 gmtoff=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @RuslanOsmanov kindly pointed out, the timezone data for Europe/Berlin was incorrect. I was able to verify this by using

```
zdump -V Europe/Berlin | grep 2017
```

In order to fix this, I performed a reinstall of tzdata which fixed the problem.

```
 apt-get --reinstall install tzdata
```